# Javascript object that references itself... any problems?

Tags: javascript

Since Javascript allows compound values to be assigned by reference, if a Javascript object references itself, it creates an infinite set of references, as visible in the console:

[image: Chrome JS console]

This looks like some sort of infinite loop, but Chrome doesn't seem to have a problem with it. Are there any memory issues or other risks doing this?

Comment: Only when used in a context that "doesn't know how to correctly terminate recursive object graphs" - this can lead to Stack Overflow errors or 'infinite recursion'. One place such an object will 'break' is with `JSON.stringify` (in particular, it throws an error when it detects recursive object graphs). Note how the Chrome console added in a `{pointers: Array(1)}` "reference" when it detected a cycle.

Comment: OTOH, from a defensive programming/programmer side, it could be argued that such an object should "only" be used in a case when such can be guaranteed to only be traversed in a manner that is cyclic-aware.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. super helpful.

Comment: Circular references were a problem in IE6, as it [could not reclaim that memory](https://web.archive.org/web/20070615160254/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929874/). Not dead soon enough. Today's browsers? Not a problem at all.

Comment: @user2864740: "Note how the Chrome console added in a {pointers: Array(1)} "reference" when it detected a cycle." This is irrelevant; Chrome represents a non-cyclic array property in the same way. Compare with `{ pointers: [1] }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of memory, it's fine. The object is just saying where it is located. It's up to you whether to ask it about it again and again.